# Sorting WooCommerce products by menu_order + popularity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make an option to sort WooCommerce products by menu_order + popularity.

So products will be ordered by menu_order, and if they have the same menu_order they will be displayed ordered by popularity

I thought this simple code will work, but it's not:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'add_default_orderby_args');

function add_default_orderby_args($args)
{
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean((string) wp_unslash($_GET['orderby'])) : wc_clean(get_query_var('orderby'));

    if ('recommended' == $orderby_value) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order popularity';
        $args['order']   = 'DESC';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't make Andriy Kovalenko code to work, don't know if it's my fault, but anyway, this code seems to be working:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args($args)
{
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));

    if ('recommended' == $orderby_value) {
        $args['orderby']  = ['menu_order' => 'DESC', 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC'];
        $args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
    }

    return $args;
}
```